# how to access the item in an array in a script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I am new to vue and Laravel Framework.

I wanted to fetch data from **api** and display those data dynamically.

I have created a table named  'Progress' and seeded  some data. I have used API resource to fetch data .

I have created a vue template to fetch the data from the api.

this is my template

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h1> Goals </h1>
    <p id="demo"></p>
       <div  class= "progress progress-bar-segmented"  v-for = "progressdata in progress" v-bind:id="progressdata.id">
             <div> {{ progressdata.name }} </div>
             <div id="div1" class="progress-bar" style="width:20%">{{ progressdata.goal }}</div>
              <div id="div2" class="progress-bar value" style="width:20%">{{ progressdata.value }}</div>
        </div>
</div>

</template>
```

The problem is how to access the individual values like `{{ progressdata.goal }}` and `{{ progressdata.value }}` from a progress array in a script?

If I use `var a = this.progressdata.goal` inside a method. I could receive  `undefined value`

I know that they are accessible only within that scope.. How to access them in a script individually?

this is my script

```
<script>

  export default {
     data: function() {
            return {
              progress: [],

          }
        },

    mounted() {
       this.loadContents();
       this.start();
       setInterval(this.loadContents, 1000);


    },
    methods: {

     loadContents: function() {
           //load Api
           axios.get('/api/progress')
           .then((response) => {
               this.progress = response.data.data;
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
    });
  },

  start: function() {
        var  allProgressElements = document.getElementsByClassName('progress');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(allProgressElements, function(el) {
        var targetDOM = $(el).getElementsByClassName('value');
        targetDOM.innerHTML = json.data[targetDOM.id].value;
       });
       }
}
}
</script>
```

```
Anyone could help please?
thank you.
```

Comment: You can remove the start function completely. On a successful axios call, the `progress` value is set, and due to Vue's reactivity, the `v-for` will be activated. Do a `console.log` in the axios response to check the response. Is the response an array of objects, like you expect?

Comment: Thank you fo your feedback. No, i need to get the value of each item in the progress array individually for example goal and value ..How to get them ? And how to pass them inside a method in the script? Could you please help..

Comment: Inside your script (methods, computed, etc) you can access the `progress` array, and access each item in the array: `a = this.progress[0].goal`

Comment: yeah i have tried ```a = this.progress[0].goal``` in a method ..But i recieved TypeError: Cannot read property 'goal' of undefined". How to solve this ? Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things going on here:

- Useing Vue, there is hardly ever the need to use function to access the DOM directly. So eliminate those in the `start` function.
- You have a misunderstanding in code execution flow, espessially because of the axios `Promise` (see code below)
- Make sure to read all about Vue `reactivity`, `properties` and scoping.

```js
<script>

  export default {
     data: function() {
            return {
              progress: [], // The progress array is defined
          }
        },

    mounted() {
       // Component mounted, start loading of contents
       this.loadContents();

       // Note i removed code here! Because that codes was
       // executed right after the loadContents call, but
       // before the axios result came in!  
    },
    methods: {

     loadContents: function() {
           //load Api
           // The get function returns a promis
           axios.get('/api/progress')
           .then((response) => {
               // Promise resolved, now set the data:
               this.progress = response.data.data;
               // And now we can perform the start function
               this.start()
               // Maybe add the setInterval code here, although you need
               // to check if you really want to hit your server every second....
               // Better to use a websocket and let the server notify you about the progress
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
    });
  },

  start: function() {
      // And in this function we now have access to the progress array:
      for (const item of this.progress) {
         console.log(item.goal) 
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support.. is it possible to declare the item.goal in a variable like ```a=item.goal```? If I do i didn't get the result. Could you please help?

Comment: I need to create a circular progress bar with goal as target and value as server data. The value should be updated every second to 2. I am not sure how to do.?Could you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Look at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress-circular/#progress-circular than in your v-for loop, add this progress-circular, and set it's `percentage` to `:percentage="progessdata.value / progressdata.goal"` (basically it doesnt matter if you use vuetify or not, just calculate the progress in you v-for loop, you don't really need the `start` function I think)

Comment: Thanks for your support :-) I have placed the below code  from the given link.. ```<div class = "progress"

Comment: You need to `use` vuetify in `Vue`. See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/

Comment: I have included  ```uetify: new Vuetify()```in my  app.js. I recieved app.js ``` Uncaught ReferenceError: Vuetify is not defined``` .How to install vuetify in laravel project? Could you please support ? thanks

Comment: this is my template code in Front.vue.  ```<div class= "progress" v-for = "(progressdata, index) in progress" v-bind:id="progressdata.id"> >
 <div class="text-center">
    <v-progress-circular
      :rotate="360"
      :size="100"
      :width="15"
      v-bind:value="progressdata.value"
      color="teal"
    >
      {{ progressdata.value }}
    </v-progress-circular>
      </div>
      </div>````

Comment: @ Maarten Veerman. Thank you for your support and help ..Could you please help me to solve the issue in  the link which I have posted ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358632/how-to-display-circular-progress-bar-with-vuetify#```